# Constructing neighbourhoods for analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\epsilon>0$. If a complex function $f $ is analytic, can we construct a $\delta $- neighbourhood around $a $ (an arbitrary point in the domain) such that for any $x\in B (a, \delta) $, $\left|\frac {f (x)-f (a)}{x-a}-f'(a)\right|<\epsilon $?

I was trying to do this, but couldn't quite figure out how.

Comment: It is the very definition of derivative that you can do that.

Comment: The definition of analyticity suggests that the derivative is the limit obtained from all directions. It does not suggest that we can bound the error in all directions simultaneously

Comment: Yes, it does. This is exactly the definition of limit. Note that we don't "look in each direction at a time" when we compute a limit.